# Copy instance at AWS Amazon services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i want to launch a new instance at my AWS account.There i have an instance that i am running a website and i want to launch a new instance,with the informations of the old one(that i have the website) for testing purposes.I found this link:[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launch-more-like-this.html ]
If i launch the new instance and make my changes there,this will affect my old instance?I am asking for your understanding because i don't know a lot of things about the Amazon services.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing done to the new instance will impact the old one.

Not only do they not have any future connection to each other, the new one does not start out as a clone of the old in its current state.

> **Note**
>
> The Launch More Like This wizard option does not clone your selected instance; it only replicates some configuration details. To create a copy of your instance, first create an AMI from it, then launch more instances from the AMI.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launch-more-like-this.html

"Launch more like this" only means "like this one... back when it was new."